# How to show something different than the model as the value in an input in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an input that is bound to an object, like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedUser">

$scope.selectedUser = {
    name: 'john',
    id: '1234'
};
```

My question is how do I show "name" as the value of the input but still have the input bound to the object itself and not the name?

What I am trying to achieve sort of like having a value that is different from the bound model, kind of like:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="selectedUser.name" ng-model="selectedUser.id">
```

(I know this doesn't work)

Additional background (if it helps):

This input field is not interacted with directly.
A user selects a person from a list within a modal dialog, which sets selectedUser.
The reason for using an input was to make it part of the form, which makes submit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for viewValue and modelValue of ng-model.

Comment: This is it exactly. I am new to Angular... I can see other uses for this as well! thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the data in form input values (say if you're submitting it with a non-Javascript POST), then you can have non visible data in a hidden form elements

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="selectedUser.id" name="userId">
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedUser.name" name="userName">
```

Comment: I am indeed using an ajax post within my angular app, so having the model bound to an object works fine for me.